# AWS EB Error: Incorrect application version found on all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use the EB CLI to deploy an application into an environment but I seem to be getting strange errors. Is there a way to empty out previous application versions so I can upload a fresh application?

The message I see after I execute eb deploy.

```
Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

I am currently getting this error:

```
Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version [app version]
```

The logs file also seems to be getting deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 34):

I solved this by doing an instance reboot.
Redeploy worked well after reboot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you it did the trick! For those who dont see this pane, see instruction for enabling enhanced health monitoring

Answer (score 16):

The operation completed but there were errors means that your deployment did not succeed. When an application update is unsuccessful eb will keep using the last good version. So if the last good version is 48 but this deployment is 55 and eb is expecting 54, then that "error" will be present... More of a warning than an error.

Something in your application is causing the application update to fail... Use the GUI to get the full logs which will reveal the error... Fix the error and when your deployment is successful your "Incorrect application version" error will resolve.

Comment: Ah thanks, the problem is that both 'eb logs' and the gui logs show nothing after the deployment failure. One of the events says, "deleting log fragments". Do you know why that is?

Comment: Can you ssh to the instance?

Comment: The error will not be at the end, it will be further up the logs... Even after the deployment fails, lots still happens, and is logged. 'Eb logs' only returns the last 100 lines, you need the full log files.

Comment: Is this a rails application?

Comment: Logs are not very helpful at finding what's wrong during deployment.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that the issue was due to incompleteness of the permissions granted to the codepipeline/deployment service role.

You should grant `UpdateApplicationversion` permission to the associated elastic beanstalk resources for the role that you use to deploy your app.

Comment: how can I add this permission please?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the application/package version in package.json and redeploying it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and the cause was the command timeout

**Default max deployment time -Command timeout- is 600 (10 minutes)**

Go to Your Environment →  Configuration → Deployment preferences → Command timeout

Increase the Deployment preferences for example 1800

or upgrade the instance type to work faster

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in my EB application

```
Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "Sample Application"
```

As [@shiva prasad reddy puchala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9300590/shiva-prasad-reddy-puchala) mentioned, changing the application version in the package.json solved this issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the environment and deploying the new application version should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also faced this problem, and also the real problem seems to be a previous one, in my case I have CodeDeploy lacking permission on Cloud Watch, which made the deployment fail.

I can see both problems in the events section of Elastic Beanstalk.